# Facebook API Javascript JSON response

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
function getUser()
{
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Response is '+response);
       alert('Your name is ' + response.first_name);
       alert('Your last name is ' + response.last_name);
       alert('Your Gender is ' + response.gender);
       alert('Your status is '+response.username);
    }
```

How can I get the entire response like this below printed?

```
{
  "id": "blah blah", 
  "name": "blah blah", 
  "first_name": "blah blah", 
  "last_name": "blah blah", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/blah blah", 
  "username": "blah blah", 
  "hometown": {
    "id": "106442706060302", 
    "name": "Pune, Maharashtra"
  }, 
  "location": {
    "id": "106377336067638", 
    "name": "Bangalore, India"
  }, 
  "bio": "╔══╗♫ ♪♫\n║██║\n║¨o•♫\n╚═|̲̅̅●̲̅̅|̅lιlllι ♫ I LoVe MuZiK!!\n\n█║▌│█│║▌║│█║▌│║\n® Copyright © 2012 ™\n█║▌│█│║▌║│█║▌│║\n\nReVoLt", 
  "gender": "male", 
  "relationship_status": "Single", 
  "timezone": 5.5, 
  "locale": "en_GB", 
  "verified": true, 
  "updated_time": "2012-06-15T05:33:31+0000", 
  "type": "user"
}
```

Also by respose.name am getting the name of the user.
How can I get the location in the parameter location as it is a JSON array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use JSON.stringify(response);
it should print the entire object.

use JSON.parse() or jQuery.parseJSON(); to parse and get any properties of the response object
examples here : jsfiddle.net/epinapala/HrfkL  and  here : jsfiddle.net/epinapala/zfWWv/3

```
    var obj2 = JSON.parse('{"id":"579156356","name":"Vishal Jethani","first_name":"Vishal","last_name":"Jethani","link":"https://www.facebook.com/vishal.jethani","username":"vishal.jethani","hometown":{"id":"106442706060302","name":"Pune, Maharashtra"},"location":{"id":"106377336067638","name":"Bangalore, India"},"bio":"bye bye to bad characters","gender":"male","relationship_status":"Single","timezone":5.5,"locale":"en_GB","verified":true,"updated_time":"2012-06-15T05:33:31+0000","type":"user"}');
alert("Parsing with Json : " + obj2.location.name);​
```

For multidimensional array as asked by the requester :
THis should work : http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/WQcDg/

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse('{"work":[{"employer":{"id":"185998961446429","name":"Pvt Ltd"}}]}');

alert("Parsing with Json : " + JSON.stringify(obj2.work[0].employer.name));
```

Comment: It does print the entire object. But later i want extract data from the location parameter as i need the data in id,name. Please look in the above json response. Thanks

Comment: i just putup an example on jsfiddle.Can you try this

http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/zfWWv/3/

after you pass a valid json to parseJSON(), just access the properties by their heirarchy!

Comment: Cant it be done without jquery. As it says cant find variable jquery?

Comment: do i need to add a jquery lib for that?

Comment: "As it says cant find variable jquery?" 
is this error in your script, because you dint include jQuery?

well if you dont want to use Jquery, Use obj = JSON.parse({"yourJson" : "here"}) .. and alert(obj.location.name)

without Jquery .. http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/HrfkL/

Comment: If you want to use / play around more with jquery, you can use it if you want !

Comment: Hey, Thanks it works fine. Later if it is.                               "work":
[
{
"employer": {
"id": "185998961446429", 
"name": "Pvt Ltd"
}
}
] In a multidimentional array?

Comment: Glad it worked! You can Upvote this answer to help others :)

Peace!

Comment: "work":
[
{
"employer": {
"id": "185998961446429", 
"name": "Pvt Ltd"
}
}
]How would i do it for a multidimentional array?

Comment: Help me with the multidimentional array comment. As i mentioned up.

Comment: THis should work :  http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/WQcDg/
var obj2 = JSON.parse('{"work":[{"employer":{"id":"185998961446429","name":"Pvt Ltd"}}]}');

alert("Parsing with Json : " + JSON.stringify(obj2.work[0].employer.name));

Edited the answer too!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use FB Graph api. and if you want more information then you have to use like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/579156356

https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAHTRFEKjKcvFe1W2NJTu1Gsy20cNWEe0Dh98KoOhJEInZB1kXrMprNUaN6nq8FZA7YMZBvNVLwuz6pglh1SIBbZCnEECOAZDZD
```

i am useing like this.

```
function(evt){
     console.log(evt.target.responseText);
     var FB_obj = JSON.parse(evt.target.responseText);
     console.log("fb id >>"+FB_obj.id);
     console.log("fb name >>"+FB_obj.name);
}
```

Comment: JDEV,I am using the graph API. wanted to ask how can print the same response on console.log. As the above json response?

Comment: Please check my answer i just edited something like i got callback function with event.

Comment: This returns id,name of the user. I wanted the id,name from the location parameter as it is a json array? Help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery get Json method isted using pure javascript,

1. You need to get Accesstoken
2. Replace your access token below the texted YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN field

I used this library to get the date formatted,
https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

```
    $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/5973249561/events/?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=id,name,description,start_time,place,cover,end_time&limit=4",
      function(result){
        for(x = 0; x < result.data.length; x++) {
          var id = result.data[x].id;
          var name = result.data[x].name;
          var cover = result.data[x].cover.source;
          var date = new Date(result.data[x].start_time);
          var place = result.data[x].place.name;
          var day = date.toString('dd');
          var month = date.toString('MMM');
          var url = 'https://facebook.com/'+id;
          var time = date.toString("hh:mm tt");
          $("#evt").append(name);
        }
      });
```