# How to remove commas, brackets in python using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

These are the contents of my text file  (eg:abc.doc):

```
{'data': [{'name': 'abc'},{'name': 'xyz'}]}
```

After opening the file in python; how do i remove all the brackets, quotes and commas.
The final output should be:

```
data:
name:abc
name:xyz
```

Comment: Is this always the format of the input string?  could it be `[{'data': [{'name': 'abc'},{'name': 'xyz'}]}]`?

Comment: This is the string i obtain using facebook graph api, which i write into a doc file. So it is same always.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel! This format is called JSON, use a *JSON parsing* library.

Comment: Check the Facebook API docs. Other responses will likely be in the JSON format too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to turn it into a python structure, then print the values:

```
with open(r'd:\output1.doc', 'r') as inputfile:
    inputstring = inputfile.read()

data = ast.literal_eval(inputstring)
for key, sublist in data.items():
    print '{}:'.format(key)
    for subdict in sublist:
        for key, value in subdict.items():
            print('{}:{}'.format(key, value))
```

For your example that results in:

```
>>> inputstring = "{'data': [{'name': 'abc'},{'name': 'xyz'}]}"
>>> import ast
>>> data = ast.literal_eval(inputstring)
>>> for key, sublist in data.items():
...     print '{}:'.format(key)
...     for subdict in sublist:
...         for key, value in subdict.items():
...             print '{}:{}'.format(key, value)
... 
data:
name:abc
name:xyz
```

*However*: If you got this from the Facebook API, then you transcribed the format incorrectly. The Facebook API gives you JSON data, which uses *double quotes (`"`) instead*:

```
{"data": [{"name": "abc"},{"name": "xyz"}]}
```

in which case you should use the [`json` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) that comes with Python:

```
import json

data = json.loads(inputstring)
# process the same way as above.
```

If you have a filename, you can ask  the library to read straight from the file using:

```
data = json.load(filename)  # note, no `s` after `load`.
```

Comment: If the format is always the same, I don't see anything wrong with `ast.literal_eval` here -- Sure it's valid JSON and you could use that too, but I don't see any drawbacks to ast.literal_eval either (and this answer actually shows how to print the data in the form that OP requested)

Comment: Actually, it is *not* valid JSON: *ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Most possibly because your instinct said this was not a valid json looking at the quoted string??? :-)

Comment: @Abhijit: I am a little travel-tired; I feel like I am going scaly-eyed.. :-P

Comment: It gives me invalid syntax. Instead of inputstring i gave the location of doc file like data = ast.literal_eval('c:\abc.doc')

Comment: `literal_eval` is given the string itself, not a filename. Open the file and read the data first.

Comment: @MartijinPeiters Python 2.7 with pyscripter for python 2.7.

Comment: That's what I get for not using JSON very frequently at all :)

Comment: @AaronMisquith: `files2.read()`, not `files2`. And open the file for reading, not writing! Use `open(r'd:\output1.doc', 'r+')` to open, then read the data, then use `files2.seek(0)` to rewind, then use `.write()` on it. By opening the file for writing you *wiped the data*.

Comment: The output that i'm getting from facebook doesnt have double-quotes just single quotes.

Comment: @AaronMisquith: It is always possible for an API to be broken, of course. The `ast.literal_eval()` trick interprets the data as Python literals (as if you typed it in as source code).

Comment: @AaronMisquith: Are you asking for a JSON response though? Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062007/facebook-api-javascript-json-response) I'd expect the Facebook API to return properly formatted JSON.

Comment: @AaronMisquith: There is no point in posting code in comments, edit your question (within reason, don't change the premise) instead. :-)

Comment: @AaronMisquith: You are reading the file but doing nothing with the return value of `.read()`.. `data = files2.read()`, then `ast.literal_eval(data)` would work a lot better!

Comment: @AaronMisquith: In fact, it'd be easier all round if you first read the data, then re-opened the file for writing (no seek needed then).

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have [json](http://www.json.org), which can be easily parsed using [pyjson](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json
obj=json.loads(u'''{'data': [{'name': 'abc'},{'name': 'xyz'}]}''')
```

Bob's your uncle now, innit?

Comment: This is not a valid json, the string is single quoted